# JSP page is loaded half scrolled by default in Safari

Tags: safari

I have a web application. It views fine in Firefox and IE. But when I use Safari, there seems to be a problem while loading pages that are long enough to have a vertical scroll bar in them. The page loads and displays the bottom or middle of the page by default. This happens only when Safari is not maximized to full screen.

Has anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. When there is a textfield that is focused, whenever the page loads or refreshes, Safari tries to keep the textfield inside the display area (unlike FF or IE). So my textfield was wayy down and so it scrolled down on every page load.